# Find domain of a function that is complicated to invert

Tags: calculus

I want to find the RANGE for the function:

$$f=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{4}{(x-1)}$$

given the DOMAIN

$$D_f=(0,1)$$

Now usually if the function is bijective you can just invert it and find the DOMAIN.

With this function if I invert it I get two big rationals with squareroots, ie complicated solutions.
I'm thinking there must be a better way to find the DOMAIN of f?
Any suggestions?
Thanks beforehand!

Alright, I feel really silly.. Now I totally understood what you did with the inequalitys. I confused the terms range and domain, which is really sad^^
I have corrected the question

Comment: I'm not sure if that notation for range is standard, but it is remniscent of the derivative of $f$ ($Df$), which could lead to some confusion.

Comment: Oh you are so correct, That's the swedish way of doing it, my mistake.
D is for "definitionsområde" which in mathematical terms is domain in swedish

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! That's interesting to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{4}{(x-1)}$ then
$f$ is continuous and has a derivative in $(0,1)$,
$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{4}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{(x+1)(3x-1)}{x^2(x-1)^2}$$
which implies that, in $(0,1)$, the function $f$ attains a minimum value at $x=1/3$.
Moreover
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=+\infty.$$
What may we conclude?

Comment: I solved this inequality and got:
$$x≠-1$$
$$x<-\frac{1}{3}$$
I don't understand what that gives us?

Comment: Well I probably did that wrong, even so, what would the inequality give us?

Comment: You are correct. $f(x)\in (0,1)$ iff  $x\in (-\infty,-1)\cup (-1,-1/3)$.

Comment: Ya, I asked the wrong question. Given the Domain I want to find the range
Sorry, I confused the terms

Comment: @einar I edited my answer. Any more doubts?

Comment: Awesome! We can conclude that the range is $$R_f=[4,+\infty.]$$
Because its continuous and d/dx exists in the domain we set the derivative to 0 to find extreme points. 
We find a min at x=1/3 which when put in the original function gives 9, the upper limit is infinity

Comment: Thanks, everything is clear